# Django: unable to save a value in models

Tags: python, django

I am currently working on a CS50 Web development SQL, Models, and Migrations and following what the tutorial says to do , yet I found that I am not able to duplicate the result at some points.

I have created a new class in models.py named Airport.

```
class Airport(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.city} ({self.code})"
```

When I try to use the `f = Airport(code="NY", city="New York")` `f.save()` function to save it, the following error occurs

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: flights_airport
```

I have checked some solutions from the internet, the first one is to do the migration again. Yet, when I do `python manage.py makemigrations`
it says

```
No changes detected
```

when I do `python manage.py migrate`, it shows a long error message with

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'flights_flight' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key:
flights_flight.origin_id contains a value 'new york' that does not have a corresponding value in flights_airport.id
```

I have also tried to delete all the data with `Airport.objects.all().delete()`

It again shows the following error code

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: flights_airport
```

I am stuck in a point that I cant do migration nor can I start it again. I'd like to know what shall I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, clear your DB with this command to completely refresh your DB rows.

```
python manage.py sqlflush # needs django above 1.9
```

Then, again

```
python manage.py makemigration
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: cant solve the problem, the error code still exit `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'flights_flight' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key:
flights_flight.origin_id contains a value 'new york' that does not have a corresponding value in flights_airport.id`

Comment: Do you have access to your database? and what database you using?

Comment: What do you mean, I am using Django, you mean accessing the database in the admin page?

Comment: No. Your django connect to some database. In your setting file you can see what database. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. The issue seems to be that after creating a Model Class "Flight", the tutorial instructed us to save some flight data in the database (and not delete it). Then we created an "Airport" class and adjusted the "Flight" class to contain a Foreign Key from the "Airport" class/database, which was empty. So it seems that when doing the migraiton the existing data could not be assigned to a foreign key. Deleting the data from the "flights" table solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the app is included in settings.

Then run python manage.py makemigrations flights

And python manage.py migrate flights

Comment: yes, I've included it in setting, the error code still exit `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'flights_flight' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: flights_flight.origin_id contains a value 'new york' that does not have a corresponding value in flights_airport.id `

Answer (score 0):

This means that there is a row in your DB in the table `flights_flights` that has an external key that tries to find in the table `flights_airport` a row with `flights_flight.origin_id == "new york"`, which doesn't exists, hence it can't perform the migration correctly.
Simply deleting the incriminating row in the `flights` table should allow you to fix this.

Comment: I have changed the models.py field and deleted those lines with foreign. Howevever, I am still not able to do `python manage.py migrate`, the same error code exist

Comment: Your early changes applied on your database and only deleting model codes didn't remove row on database

Comment: I used the software sqlitebrowswer https://sqlitebrowser.org/ to view the db file and to delete the data, problem solved!